# Recuperar dados do Mysql e salvar em um vetor

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile

Reformulando a pergunta.. Tenho um banco de dados MySQL, dentro dele contém uma tabela chamada mapa, dentro da tabela mapa tenho os campos idmapa (auto_increment), lat (que armazena a latitude de uma posição do mapa), lng (que armazena a longitude de uma posição do mapa), detalhe (que armazena os detalhes que o usuário pode inserir, referente a posição do mapa) e imagem (que armazena somente o nome da imagem referente a posição do mapa). O script em ajax abaixo envia os dados que quero salvar no banco para um arquivo php. Dentro do arquivo php, tenho um if, que irá receber os dados enviados pelo ajax para assim salvar no banco de dados dentro da tabela mapa os respectivos dados de acordo com os campos do banco de dados citados acima.

O que quero fazer: Preciso fazer o processo inverso, ou seja, requisitar para o php os dados da tabela mapa, utilizando ajax na requisição, porém, após requisitados, quero salvar estes dados em vetores específicos, para que assim, posteriormente  eu possa criar um loop para adicionar estes dados à uma marcação no mapa. 
OBS: Estou usando o Google maps API Javascript.

PHP salvando no banco

```
 if($_GET['acao']=='btn_finaliza'){

 $latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
 $longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
 $detalhe = $_GET['detalhe'];
 $imagem = $_GET['imagem'];

 $SQL = "INSERT INTO mapa (lat, lng, detalhe, imagem) VALUES ('$latitude','$longitude','$detalhe','$imagem')";

 $re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve)or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo $SQL;
 }
```

Script Ajax que envia os dados para o php

```
  $.ajax({

  type: "get",
  url: $server+"/conecta.php",
                 data: "latitude="+$tlati+"&longitude="+$tlong+"&detalhe="+$detalhe+"&imagem="+$imagem+"&acao=btn_finaliza",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    location.href='#page_mapa';
                                    navigator.notification.alert('Problema cadastrado', '', 'ok');}

  });
```

Após avaliar as dicas, estou tentando desta forma:

PHP:

```
if($_GET['acao']== 'marcacao'){

 $SQL = "SELECT * FROM mapa";
 $resultados = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
 $res=mysql_fetch_array($resultados); 

 if ($linha = @mysql_num_rows($resultados) == 0){
 echo 0;
 }

 else{
     echo $linha['lat'];
     echo $linha['lng'];
     exit;
}
}
```

Java Script e Ajax:

```
     function marcacao(){       
        $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: $server+"/conecta.php",
        data: 'acao=marcacao',
        success: function(data) {
        // le o retorn de data, que já será um array/vetor, e popula seu mapa com API do Google Maps

            var map = new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById("map"), 
                    { 
                      center : new google.maps.LatLng($lat, $lng), 
                      zoom : 5, 
                      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
                    }
            );

            var image = 'images/ray.png';

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                        title : "VOCÊ ESTÁ AQUI: "+$lat+", "+$lng,
                        position : new google.maps.LatLng($lat, $lng),
                        map: map,
                        icon: image
                 });

            marker.setMap(map);  
          }

    });

   }
```

Porém, acho que a forma como estou passando as variáveis do php para o javascript (echo $linha["lat"] e echo $linha["lng"]]) estão erradas, e por isso as marcações no mapa não estão sendo feitas.

Comment: Tem algum código para colocar na pergunta?

Comment: Olá G. Vilela, você poderia colocar parte do seu código para que possamos melhor responde-lo?

Comment: Tenta explicar melhor, porque numa parte disseste inserir e noutra disseste buscar, e o teu script está `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

@G.Vilela

Vc já tem 90% do caminho andado, então está fácil.

IMPORTANTE: Não sou programador PHP.

**BACKEND - API REST**

Ao invés de fazer um PHP para responder à tudo `conecta.php`, crie uma estrutura com mais cara de API mesmo que irá deixar seu código mais organizado, semântico e responsável.

```
/api
/api/mapa/
/api/mapa/get.php
/api/mapa/post.php
/api/mapa/put.php
/api/mapa/delete.php
```

Onde:

- **GET**: Para recuperar dados
- **POST**: Para inserir dados
- **PUT**: Para alterar dados
- **DELETE**: Para excluir dados

Então seu `/api/mapa/post.php`, responsável por inserir dados de MAPA, ficará algo assim:

```
 $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
 $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
 $detalhe = $_POST['detalhe'];
 $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];

 $SQL = "INSERT INTO mapa (lat, lng, detalhe, imagem) VALUES ('$latitude','$longitude','$detalhe','$imagem')";

 $re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve) or die(mysql_error());
```

E, para recuperar dados do mapa, faça o `/api/mapa/get.php` algo assim:

```
 $latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
 $longitude = $_GET['longitude'];

 $SQL = "SELECT * FROM mapa WHERE lat = $latitude AND lng = $longitude";

 $re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve) or die(mysql_error()); 

 // Trecho para retornar o resultado da consulta em JSON
 echo "[";
 // Para cada linha retornado pelo SELECT
    echo "{\"lat\": $lat, \"lng\": $lng, \"detalhe\": \"$detalhe\", \"imagem\": \"$imagem\" }"
 echo "]";
```

**FRONDEND - JQUERY AJAX**

Já no seu script, para inserir dados fica assim:

```
var data = {
    latitude: $tlati,
    longitude: $tlong,
    detalhe: $detalhe,
    imagem: $imagem
};

$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: $server+"/api/mapa/post.php",
  data: JSON.Stringfy(data),
  success: function(data) {
      location.href='#page_mapa';
      navigator.notification.alert('Problema cadastrado', '', 'ok');
  }
});
```

E para consultar:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: $server+"/api/mapa/get.php?lat="+$lat+"&lng="+lng,
  success: function(data) {
      // le o retorn de data, que já será um array/vetor, e popula seu mapa com API do Google Maps
  }
});
```

Comment: Ótima dica, irei organizar o código futuramente!

Comment: e a sua sugestão de echo não funcionou aqui

Comment: @G.Vilela, é que, como eu disse, eu não sei PHP, mas esse é caminho das pedras. Espero que alguém de PHP possa complementar essa resposta e te ajudar ainda mais. MAs a ideia é fazer o PHP retornar um JSON.